# jquery selector. search of an input with multiple same id but is inside a unique div

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="one">
     <input id="ac1"> </input>
</div>
<div id="two">
     <input id="ac1"> </input>
</div>
```

How can i make a jquery selector that gives me the input inside div with id "one".

This is just an example code above. The importance is that i can search of a input that have many of same id:s but is inside a unique div.

Comment: **`id` must be unique per-document.** There is no option to stick with duplicate `id` values in a page, just like creating invalid HTML is no option (which is what duplicate ids do). You **must fix the HTML**. Use `class="ac1"` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good practice to have to two elements with the same ID. IDs should be unique.

But you can try this:

```
$('#one #ac1')
```

This means select an item with ID #ac1 which is inside an item with ID #one.

Comment: **This is not a matter of bad practice; `id` being unique is an absolute *must*.** There is no option to stick with duplicate `id` values in a page, just like creating invalid HTML is no option (which is what duplicate ids do).

Comment: @connexo You are correct but I don't know why he asked this question. Maybe these IDs are inside of ifs on the back and only one gets sent to front??

Comment: OP is asking jQuery, so clearly they are asking purely frontend / DOM.

Comment: I already said that IDs should be unique... I just answered the question. Otherwise, yes you are completely correct.

Comment: Your choice of words clearly suggests that sticking with duplicate ids is not a good option, but still an option.  *should* is **wrong**. ids **must**  be unique.

Comment: @connexo Yes. They should be unique as the name suggest (Identification). Period.
I only said my answer is doable. I didn't mean he should do it.

Comment: Again, they **should** be unique **is plain wrong**. They **must** be unique. From the spec: *When specified on HTML elements, the id attribute value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's tree and must contain at least one character.* https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes:the-id-attribute